# javascript the good parts, anonymous functions, jquery validate, and (json?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, anonymous-function

I could make a separate function, but this can be done in one line, so an anon function seems right to me.  Here's what I have thus far, it's returning a syntax error.

```
$('#submitAll').validate({
    rules: {
      preferred: {
        required: true,
        validPreferred: $('#preferred').val(),
        remote: {
          type: "post",
          url: "./postlocation.php",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          async: false,
          data: {
            phone: {
              //Write me, function getPreferred(preferred.val)
              'number': {function(idPhone){return idPhone.val();}: $('#preferred')},
              'sid': Math.random()
            }
          }
        } 
      }
    }
```

Don't get hung up on the closing squigglies.  I'm trying to set the 'number' field in data to $('#preferred').val().

Right now, I think it's possible to do without an anon function even, but that requires multiple levels of $'s, and I'm not sure my ape brain can take it.

Comment: You do not have your function closed }); at the end

Answer (score 1):

It's right! You have syntaxt error in JSON expression used after 'number' property. Who said 'function' comes  after '{'?! This is completely wrong. Also please use nested coding style, it's for your good, not any one else. Try this:

```
$('#submitAll')
.validate(
    {
        rules: {
            preferred: {
                required: true,
                validPreferred: $('#preferred').val(),
                remote: {
                    type: "post",
                    url: "./postlocation.php",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    async: false,
                    data: {
                        phone: {
                            //Write me, function getPreferred(preferred.val)
                            'number': (
                                function(idPhone)
                                {
                                    return (idPhone.val()) ? idPhone.val() : $('#preferred').val();
                                }
                            )($("WHERE IS THE idPhone variable?!")),
                            'sid': Math.random()
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I will definitely try that.  But, real quick, js does "intelligent" ';' insertion after new lines, and so I've (Douglas Crockford) has found its best to just to '{' on the same line as where it starts.

Comment: Write as the way you can read. Use some minifier tools when you are publishing, they will put everything in a single line! ;)

Comment: I'm still seeing a syntax error, but this has the look of "correctness" to it.  I'm going to accept this.  Thanks a lot.  Actually, it's not any different than wrapping your code in:  (function(stuff) {});(stuff), I forgot all about that trick, thanks.

Comment: That's some good js right there buddy!  Check out the final solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks Mohammad, here it is:  Again, I had to bury the damn $'s but oh well, I like this solution.

```
$('#submitAll').validate({
    rules: {
      preferred: {
        required: true,
        //write me, function(preferredValue){return true || false}
        validPreferred: $('#preferred').val(),
        remote: {
          type: "post",
          url: "./postlocation.php",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: {
            phone: {
              //Write me, function getPreferred(preferred.val)
              'number': (function(idPhone) {
                          return $('#'+idPhone).val();
                        })($('#preferred').val()),
              'sid': Math.random()
            }
          }
        } 
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why you didn't just do: `$('#' + $('#preferred').val()).val()`.  Sure seems much more readable and a lot simpler.  I never understood your question or I would have suggested this in 10 seconds.

Comment: You know, in hind sight, yeah that is more readable.  But, I got hung up on the idea of avoiding burying $'s, and then, frankly, I just wanted an anon function there.  Like I said, I could do it with with burried $'s but that didn't seem javascriptian to me.

Comment: @Dale - look at what you have now.  It takes some thinking to figure out what you're trying to do.  There's nothing wrong with nesting jQuery objects when it's the straightforward way to solve things.

Comment: Actually, I beg to differ. Now, I don't battle parens.  And, it's very clear that 'number' is a function.  And.....this syntax is encountered so often that if this isn't recognizable, perhaps this might inspire ppl.  Again, your $$ is a good solution, but it doesn't feel jsian enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Now that I finally understand what you're trying to do, my suggestion is this:

```
'number': $('#' + $('#preferred').val()).val()
```

Comment: so what you're telling me is; I need to write a separate function?

Comment: @Dale - See what I added to my answer.

Comment: I wish.  Like I said multiple levels of $'s, then it resembles scheme and then I remember why I hated school.  In the html $('#preferred') is a <select> value.  So, I could stumble through the syntax of multiple $'s, but I figured an anon would be cleaner.

Comment: er, $('#preferred').val() is the tag of the number I want.

Comment: @Dale - what do you mean "`tag of the number you want"`?  What do you do with that value?

Comment: well, the id="what", actually corresponds to $('#preferred'), so,  I guess you could to id=$('#preferred').val().  And so to get at the actual number, you would have to bury the $'s.  Thanks for the help, I think I have the solution now!

Comment: In case you're interested, I have the solution, you can see what I mean about burrying $'s.

Answer (score 0):

jslint

http://www.jslint.com/

make this your best friend

```
jsl -process myfile.js
```

^ will find your syntax errors

Comment: whoa it has a web interface now and dont have the C source downloads anymore  :O